# ATTiny85 PWM frequency

Tags: arduino, embedded, frequency, led, pwm

I'm trying to use the ATTiny85 to control a bunch of LEDs. The LEDs have to be run at around 2Khz ( this is so that it doesn't flicker when being filmed). How would I change the frequency of PWM signals?

Comment: `2Khz` does not grant that the led does not flicker when filmed. It depends on many things, first the refresh rate of filming cam.

Comment: Also the exposure time of each frame.

Comment: While this is true with the default LED frequency of 60Hz. At 2Khz It will not flicker in each frame regardless if it's 24/30 fps. Exposure of each frame won't matter either since 1/2000 won't make a difference. This is for television and film.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it by setting different prescaler.

For `Timer/Counter0` are available prescaler values: `1`/`8`/`64`/`256`/`1024`.
So if you have 8MHz clock, and full 8bits PWM resolution you'll get: `31.25kHz` / `3.9kHz` / `448.28Hz` / `122Hz` / `30.5H`z

For `Timer/Counter1` are available prescaler settings: `1` / `2` / `4` / `8` / `16` / ... / `16384`. And it can be sourced by internal PLL clock (32MHz/64MHz).
So you can have prescaler set to divide source clock by `16` and at `8MHz` clock it'll be `1953.125Hz`.
With PLL Clock `32MHz` division by `64` is needed and for `64MHz` it's `128`. But using PLL Clock is not needed for such small output frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with this microcontroller, but from the [documentation](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2586-avr-8-bit-microcontroller-attiny25-attiny45-attiny85_datasheet.pdf), it seems that you would like to configure the TCCR0B register (bits 2:0, refer to pages 79-80).
There, you can select a different prescaler, or no prescaler at all.